# How to ser Xamarin ListView item as a new content

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I am using a listview in my xamarin Project.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
             HasUnevenRows="true"
             ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

This list my Items in viewmodel:

```
    var mockItems = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item { Id =1, Text = "First item", Description="This is an item description." },
        new Item { Id = 2, Text = "Second item", Description="This is an item description." },
        new Item { Id = 3, Text = "Third item", Description="This is an item description." },
        new Item { Id = 4, Text = "Fourth item", Description="This is an item description." },
        new Item { Id = 5, Text = "Fifth item", Description="This is an item description." }
    };
```

But I want to create a new seperate ViewModel and View page for an `Item` and use it in this list view. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me but I guess you want to read up on about how to add bindable properties to a `ContentView`: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-user-control/

Comment: Do you mean want to exchange ViewModel for Listview,or you can show an image with more info ?